# How to access test fixture parameters from function generating test case parameters in NUnit3?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I would like to generate test case parameters (TestCaseSource) based on test fixture parameters (TestFixtureSource) in NUnit3.

How to access the current test fixture parameters in test case source?

Comment: @Kritner The question, you link, is about how to generate fixture parameters. Not about how to generate test case parameters *based* on fixture parameters.

Comment: yeah sorry, retracted vote after i reread

Comment: @Chris `TestCaseSource` method / property could use some static method / property, for instance `TestContext`, where the information could be stored.

Comment: @TN. - sorry, I've removed my comment - you're right.

Answer (score 1):

To have access to the TestFixture parameters, would require having an instance of the fixture class available. TestFixtureSource doesn't have a particular instance avalable when generating the parameters, so what you are asking isn't possible.

What you can do is save the fixture parameters in member variables or properties on construction and access them from within your test methods.